# C using fread to read an unknown amount of data

Tags: c, stdio, fread, printf

I have a text file called test.txt

Inside it will be a single number, it may be any of the following:

```
1
2391
32131231
3123121412
```

I.e. it could be any size of number, from 1 digit up to x digits.
The file will only have 1 thing in it - this number.

I want a bit of code using `fread()` which will read that number of bytes from the file and put it into an appropriately sized variable.
This is to run on an embedded device; I am concerned about memory usage.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: is it one number or list of variable size numbers?

Comment: If you actually **must** use `fread` please explain why.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use:

```
char buffer[4096];
size_t nbytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), fp);

if (nbytes == 0)
    ...EOF or other error...
else
    ...process nbytes of data...
```

Or, in other words, provide yourself with a data space big enough for any valid data and then record how much data was actually read into the string.  Note that the string will not be null terminated unless either `buffer` contained all zeroes before the `fread()` or the file contained a zero byte.  You cannot rely on a local variable being zeroed before use.

It is not clear how you want to create the 'appropriately sized variable'.  You might end up using dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`) to provide the correct amount of space, and then return that allocated pointer from the function.  Remember to check for a null return (out of memory) before using it.

Comment: Will that reserve 4096 bytes of space even if i only use say 4 bytes...or will that not happen?!

Comment: Yes - that reserves 4096 bytes.  If you need to know how big the file is before reading it, you can use `fstat(fileno(fp))` or play with `fseek()` and `ftell()` to find out how big the file is.  But remember that the length of the file could change between the time you test and the time you read.

Comment: Well if memory is tight that reservation is really heavy, infact there is almost certainly no way I would be able to do that with this method efficiently.

Comment: So, use 16 instead of 4096; or 32, or any other size that's bigger than the biggest number of digits you expect to deal with.

Comment: (Note: the `fstat()` function takes two arguments: it should be more like: `struct stat sb; fstat(fileno(fp), &sb));` but you should also test the result of `fstat()`.  It shouldn't fail, but funnier things have been known to happen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid over-reading, `fread` is not the right function. You probably want `fscanf` with a conversion specifier along the lines of `%100[0123456789]`...

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) to move your file stream location to the end of the file:

```
fseek(file, SEEK_END, SEEK_SET);
```

and then using [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ftell/) to get the position of the cursor in the file — this returns the position in bytes so you can then use this value to allocate a suitably large buffer and then read the file into that buffer.

I have seen warnings saying this may not always be 100% accurate but I've used it in several instances without a problem — I think the issues could be dependant on specific implementations of the functions on certain platforms.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and see if it works, this is C on an embedded device so who knows!

Comment: Pretty sure I used this technique on the Nintendo DS a while ago, and it worked there — obviously not quite the same but it could be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how clever you need to be with the number conversion... If you do not need to be especially clever and fast, you can read it a character at a time with `getc()`. So,
- start with a variable initialized to 0.
- Read a character, multiply variable by 10 and add new digit.
- Then repeat until done.
Get a bigger sized variable as needed along the way or start with your largest sized variable and then copy it into the smallest size that fits after you finish.